# How do I call variable into another function from another function

Tags: python-2.7, function, boolean, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

I'm working on a game and am stuck on a part where a key is supposed to unlock the door of a room. Now, after some searching, I've come across that i can't call a variable that exists in one function, into another function: as i have been trying to by setting i.e.`key_picked = True` under a conditional in the *kitchen function*. And then, using a conditional in the *room function*, with the `key_picked`in a Boolean expression.

So, how do i work around this?

```
def kitchen(already_there=False):
    if choice02_key == "pick key" or choice02_key == "0" or choice02_key == "key":
        print("---------------------------------------------------------")
        print "You picked the key. It probably unlocks some door."
        key_picked = True
        kitchen(already_there=True)



def room01(already_there=False):
    if key_pick == True:
        print("---------------------------------------------------------")
        print "You unlocked the room using the key."
    else:
        print "This room is locked."
        entrance_hall(already_there=True)
```

Comment: That's a lot of code! How about boiling this down to a few-line example. Just something simple to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll edit it

Comment: Pass the variable to the function? It's not entirely clear what the issue is.

Comment: Once i've picked the key in the game, the key_picked is set to true in the kitchen function. Howevere, now when I want to go the room, i get an error that "key_picked" is not defined. So how do i fix that or is there is a way around

Comment: Pass the variable to the function?

Comment: I'm new, would you be kind enough to show me how? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the variable in a parameter. For example:

1. Define `keyPicked` in `room01`.
2. Call `kitchen(already_there, keyPicked)` from `room01`.

   3. Make the assignment you want.
3. Then, you will have the value you want in `keyPicked`.

For example, imagine I have a function that add 10 to a number. This will be better to return the value, but it is just to show you how can you do it.

```
def add_ten(number):
    number = number + 10

def main():
    number = 5
    print('Number is:', number)
    add_ten(number)
    print('Number is:', number)
```

Output:

```
Number is: 5
Number is: 15
```